# Import csv to excel with headers in last row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have daily csv files that I need to create reports from. The headers for the csv are in the last row, the first row is a discard-able comment.

I want to be able to open my workbook and run a macro that will:

1. Prompt me to select the appropriate csv file
2. Prompt me for a worksheet name and create a worksheet of that name
3. Pull in the data to the new worksheet
4. Cut the headers from the last row and replace the first row with them

(4) has been the sticking point. The files have an unknown number of rows so I need to identify that last row as part of the process. They also can vary the number of columns so I can't used a fixed header set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this.

```
Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address
```

You will get the Address of right bottom cell.

Comment: Thanks, that was the key. I've solved the issue with the following, and I'll adjust my import to ignore the 1st row  `Sub cutlastrow()
    Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Select
    Rows(ActiveCell.Row).Cut
    Rows(1).Insert
End Sub `